# Can you narrow a phones location to the cm?

Tags: android, mobile

Id like to narrow down the location of a phone to the cm or less than a foot (nothing creepy I promise :). Say there was a room full of people I would like 1 user to be able to look though an augmented reality view on their phone to find another user.

Only problem is the location data, I know gps is probably out since I think its only accurate to 10-15 meters? Could you do something with the wifi points, ie have a couple and measure ping time between them to work out location? Or does this technology already exist? Thanks C

Comment: No, not wifi. This question has been asked many times. On the other hand, BLE beacons could work, but someone would need to set them up (which is probably not possible in your case).

Comment: Beacons look interesting, they calculate location by connected or not though right, so theres no triangulation? If you had a lot in a room though you could more or less pinpoint somone to within a foot?

Comment: OK, just for fun (but seriously): If you are so close... why don't you call yourself by voice?

Comment: haha, im not looking for myself! Imagine large room with 50 people seated, someone wants me to find them...

Comment: No, there is triangulation. A good example is the San Francisco Airport. The place is loaded with them, the airport's api gives you an index of where the beacons are located exactly, so you can triangulate everything. Another thing you could do is have the person's phone ringer go off, but use infrasound so that no one can hear it. I'm just not sure if the phone is capable of emitting good infra-sounds in a large room of people thought. I have an infra-sound remote-controlled car, but that thing came with an attachment that connects to the audio port of my phone, so it's using its own speaker.

Comment: Still joking, but it could be an alternate idea: what about a laser pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Android provides basically two location provider :

- GPS
- Network

GPS is the most accurate source which you don't want to use and it's slow.

Network location provider is false but less accurate than gps.

So the only hope is GPS.

Comment: GPS hasn't got the required accuracy.